# Custom FormControl Validator function won't run

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, customvalidator, form-control

I'm attempting to utilize a custom validator in the form of this method

```
uniqueCodeValidator(control) {
if (this.products) {
  for (const p of this.products) {
    if (p.id === control.value && !this.todoid) {
      return { idExists: true };
     }
   }
  return null;
 }
} // uniqueCodeValidator
```

and I'm loading it into my FormControl like this:

```
 this.id = new FormControl('', Validators.compose([this.uniqueCodeValidator.bind(this),
  Validators.required]));
```

My html:

```
<mat-form-field >
    <input matInput placeholder="Product Id" type="text" formControlName="id">
    <mat-hint *ngIf="id.errors && (id.dirty || id.touched)" align="end"
              [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}">
      <p *ngIf="id.hasError('required')">Product Id is required.</p>
      <p *ngIf="!id.hasError('required') && id.hasError('idExists')">Unique Id Required
    </mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
```

My question is, why does my "Required" validator work but not the custom validator method uniqueCodeValidator(control)? I get no errors, it simply doesn't seem to actually touch the method. Is this possibly an issue with how I'm loading it into my validator array?